# Server 2003 IIS6 File version issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I'm running two server 2003 boxes with IIS6 that are in a dmz.  I also have a server 2003 box running IIS6 behind a firewall inside the dmz.  So, what I basically have is a staging environment in the dmz and my production environment outside the dmz.  This is for serving up a small business website.

All three servers have an instance of a cms running on them and my staging server is used for updating and publishing content to my two production servers.  The problem that I'm having is that only one of the production servers actually updates the files of the website.  The other one simply rolls them back to a version that is about a week old.  These are .ascx files that the developers use for building the site.

Any ideas on why this would happen...I don't think it is the cms as the other two boxes don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas what you could check:

- Are you using some kind of reverse proxy for that server?
- Did you check if the folder of the home directory of the site points to the right directory?
- Is the host header in your IIS configuration the right one? Maybe there is another web site responding to the host header (domain name) in question?
- what happens when you put a static file (html, txt, image) into the directory? Is it available when you try to access it from the browser?